# ¿Como descargar Symfony para obtenerlo en el localhost?

Tags: symfony2, symfony3

He descargado Symfony por la primera vez en mi nuevo ordenador. He creado mi primer proyecto en la carpeta `Home`. Soy capaz utilizarlo para crear bundles pero no puedo obtenerlo en el localhost. ¿Como puede hacer para obtenerlo aquí ?[image: Symfony error]

No parece que tengo los resultados esperados por Muriado cuando hizo su comando :

```
:~$ php bin/console server:run
Could not open input file: bin/console
```

Utiliso Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: ¿Cuál es la ruta absoluta de la carpeta Symfony?

Comment: @ReneLimon Pienso que esta en el `Home`. Si no esta la respuesta adecuada, como puede hacer para obtenerla ?

Comment: me refiero a la ruta del folder. Por ejemplo: C:\wamp\www\Sympony o /var/www/html/Sympony

Comment: Primero que nada, ¿tienes instalado xampp o similar? Al instalarlo, ¿hiciste algo parecido a este turorial? http://www.calbertts.com/blog/articulo/instalar-symfony-en-ubuntu-con-xampp

Comment: @x4mp73r Si, me recuerdo descargar lampp pero no hizo ejactamente algo paercido al tutorial. He utilisado https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2

Comment: @ReneLimon var/www/html tiene solamente `myproject` y `index.html`

Comment: debes poner la carpeta Symfony debe estar dentro de /var/www/html/

Comment: @ReneLimon ... No acepta mover...

Comment: debes cambiar los permisos de las carpetas con chmod y el propietario con chown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ejecutar en consola el siguiente comando:

```
php app/console server:run
```

Para versiones 2.8 e inferiores

```
php bin/console server:run
```

Para versiones 3 en adelante.

Esto usará el servidor BUILT-IN de php, habilitando (normalmente) la url localhost:8000 con el entorno de desarrollo.

Otra opción es configurar un vhost de apache (veo que es tu servidor)
Puedes ver como hacerlo en http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html, pero a grandes rasgos, necesitas esto:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web
    <Directory /var/www/project/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Donde `domain.tld` es el domino que usarás para acceder (puede ser localhost o un dominio redireccionado a tu host) `www.domain.tld` es un alias de ese dominio (uno secundario, si lo usas) y `/var/www/project/web` es la ruta a la carpeta `web` de tu proyecto en symfony.

Comment: `:~/myproject$ php app/console server:run Could not open input file: app/console`

Comment: Has probado con `php bin/console server:run`? Te he puesto las dos opciones porque no sé que versión de symfony estás usando.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo mejor usar el comando que está en la carpeta bin si es las versiones más recientes de symfony el comando es

> php console server:run

, Symfony configura un servidor web de pruebas listo para usar en localhost:8000.

Answer (score 1):

Todo lo que hay que hacer es darle permisos a los archivos que acabas de descargar, ve hasta el directorio en donde tienes la carpeta Symfony y ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 Symfony
```

Con esto ya deberias poder ejecutar desde el navegador los archivos del framework

Answer (score -1):

Es raro que quieras que corra en localhost/symfony, a mi me corre directamente en localhost; de todas maneras la carpeta de tu proyecto symfony deberias colocarla dentro de tu entorno xamp u otro q tengas instalado, para lograr esto debes seguir el **[tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/master/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications-without-the-installer)** u otro que te sea mas claro.

Comment: ecanro, por favor **[edit] tu respuesta** agregando mas información. Las respuestas de tipo enlace no son del todo aceptadas. Por favor revisa: **[cómo escribo una buena respuesta - Ofrece contexto para los enlaces](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.

Comment: creo q la solucion a tu inconveniente es editar el archivo httpd.conf que esta en apache\conf\ y cambiar los directorios por defecto de la aplicacion, algo asi: DocumentRoot "C:/AppServ/www"
#DocumentRoot C:/AppServ/symfony/project/web
#<Directory C:/AppServ/symfony/project/web>
<Directory "C:/AppServ/www">, en este caso comentas los del entorno y agregas los de symfony de acuerdo a donde tengas tu projecto (mi ejemplo es de windows)

Comment: por favor **[edit] tu respuesta**. [Los comentarios son temporales](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Saludos.